# Free up numbers from string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very annoying output format from a program for my x,y,r values, namely:

```
circle(201.5508,387.68505,2.298685) # text={1}
circle(226.21442,367.48613,1.457215) # text={2}
circle(269.8067,347.73605,1.303065) # text={3}
circle(343.29599,287.43024,6.5938) # text={4}
```

is there a way to get the 3 numbers out into an array without doing manual labor?

So I want the above input to become

```
201.5508,387.68505,2.298685
226.21442,367.48613,1.457215
269.8067,347.73605,1.303065
343.29599,287.43024,6.5938
```

Comment: I laughed at "manual labor". If only I could write all my code without manual labor :(

Comment: I think you want to use `.split()` but not really sure with the limited info

Comment: Also what has this got to do with numpy?

Comment: please show what you've tried thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean that the circle(...) construct is the output you want to parse.  Try something like this:

```
import re

a = """circle(201.5508,387.68505,2.298685) # text={1}
circle(226.21442,367.48613,1.457215) # text={2}
circle(269.8067,347.73605,1.303065) # text={3}
circle(343.29599,287.43024,6.5938) # text={4}"""

for line in a.split("\n"):
    print [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", line)]
```

Otherwise, you might mean that you want to call circle with numbers taken from an array containing 3 numbers, which you can do as:

```
arr = [343.29599,287.43024,6.5938]
circle(*arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit unorthodox, but as the format of your file is valid Python code and there are probably no security risks regarding untrusted code, why not just simply define a `circle` function which puts all the circles into a list and execute the file like:

```
circles = []

def circle(x, y, r):
    circles.append((x, y, r))

execfile('circles.txt')
```

`circles` is now list containing triplets of `x`, `y` and `r`:

```
[(201.5508, 387.68505, 2.298685),
 (226.21442, 367.48613, 1.457215),
 (269.8067, 347.73605, 1.303065),
 (343.29599, 287.43024, 6.5938)]
```